# pass a pointer as a memory address and make it permanent

Tags: c++, pointers

i've just begin to approach in cpp. so mayebe it is a simple problem, mayebe it is a structural problem and i have to change my design.

i have 3 facts and 1 problem.

#### fact 1:

i have a Gesture class with a vector of Point inside

```
vector<Point> Gesture::getPoints();
```

the Gesture instances recive the vector in the constructor so i think it could be normal vector (no pointer). vectors are not shared between gestures neither a gesture change its own points (aside normalization).

#### fact 2:

Gesture class has a static method that normalize all points between [0:w]. normalize take a memory address to normalize in-place. i think that normalization in place could be a nice thing. this normalization method is used by widgets to visualize the path in vector for normalize point between 0 and width-of-the-widget

```
static void Gesture::normalize(vectot<Point> &pts, int w);
```

#### fact 3:

i have a widget that visualize points:

```
void MyWidget::setGestures(vector <Gesture *> gs)
```

because the gesture is produced by another widget dinamically i thought that it has been handy to work with a vector of pointer and can do some `new Gesture` calls.

#### problem:

i have several widget that visualize gesture. each one with a different width (== different normalization).

the first time i use:

```
Gesture::rescale(this->w, this->points);
Gesture * g = new Gesture(getPoints(), centroids);
```

and it's everything ok

the second time i have:

```
vector<Gesture* > gs = foo();
int num_gesture = gs.size();
for (int i = 0; i < num_gesture; ++i) {
    vector<Point> pts = gs.at(i)->getPoints();
    Gesture::rescale( widget->getWidth(), pts );
}
widget->setGestures(gs);
```

and here there are problem because this widget is drawing not normalized points.

i have tried some crazyness with pointers but if the program does not crash.. anyway it not normalized. and it get some error like:  pointer to a temporary.

i don't knwo what to think, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is a little confusing, the problem seems to be that Gesture::getPoints() returns a vector and not a reference to a vector, so it actually returns a copy to the internal vector, and so changing it does not modify the gesture object itself.

Comment: i've changed and made `vector<Point> &Gesture::getPoints();` but no new result : (

Comment: @nkint - you still need to store it in a reference, otherwise it will still be a copy: vector<Point>& pts = gs.at(i)->getPoints();

Comment: it's still not clear why but it resolved. thanks. what can i google to understand how stuffs really works behind the hood?

Comment: Probably 'returning a reference', but I couldn't find a good enough explanation myself... Basically you changed 'pts' to become of type 'reference to a vector', which means it is not a variable on its own but just another name for another variable. In this case - the one returned by getPoints(). So when you modify pts, you actually modify the original variable - the member of Gesture.